# Android Animation Drawable Error with BitmapDrawable

Tags: android, drawable, android-animation, animationdrawable

I am now writing a program to play a list of image using AnimationDraawable in android application. The list of images are download from the server. But I have encountered error in my program that cannot add the drawable to the AnimationDrawable. Can anyone help me?

Here is my logCat capture:

```
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422):    at com.tlab.shopping.Itemview$itemanimation.doInBackground(Itemview.java:1036)
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422):    at com.tlab.shopping.Itemview$itemanimation.doInBackground(Itemview.java:1)
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-26 00:45:07.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17422):    ... 5 more
```

Here is my piece of code:

```
public static class itemanimation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, AnimationDrawable>{
    public Itemview myActivity;
    public  itemanimation(Itemview a)
    {
        myActivity = a;
    }

protected void onPreExecute(){
 //text.setText("load");
}

protected AnimationDrawable doInBackground(String... x){
Bitmap bmImg = null;
URL myFileUrl =null; 
String code = x[0];
String cur_url = null;
ImageView im = (ImageView) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

AnimationDrawable anim = null;          
Object ob = im.getBackground();          
anim = (AnimationDrawable) ob;  

for (int frameIndex = 0; frameIndex < 4; frameIndex++) {

    cur_url = "http://137.189.97.18/image/" + code + frameIndex +".jpg";
    try {   
    myFileUrl= new URL(cur_url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
    HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    int length = conn.getContentLength();
    int[] bitmapData =new int[length];
    byte[] bitmapData2 =new byte[length];
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

    bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmImg, 150, 150,true);

    Drawable bmpImgDrawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, code + frameIndex + ".jpg");
    anim.addFrame(bmpImgDrawable, 250);

    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
anim.setOneShot(false);
return anim;

}

protected void onProgressUpdate(){

}

protected void onPostExecute(AnimationDrawable z){
ImageView image = (ImageView) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setBackgroundColor(00000000);
//image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
image.setBackgroundDrawable(z);
z.stop();          
z.start(); 
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because it is not an AnimationDrawable. It is just an image, so it is a BitmapDrawable.

Comment: While this may provide an answer, it should be improved to include some code or some additional explanation.

Comment: @WimOmbelets Well, it is just a class cast exception. And I don;t know what I must provide to make that casting work.

Comment: Maybe explain why it won't work the current way, how to make it work with AnimationDrawable, how to change the code... ? (your answer is on "low quality post" review queue and as it is, it might get deleted)